# Override multi_insert_sql_strategy used in Sequel multi_insert

Tags: ruby, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sequel

Is there a way to override the `multi_insert_sql_strategy` that is specified when using methods like `multi_insert`? I am using the ODBC adapter which falls back to `:separate` as the strategy. The database that I am connecting to (Snowflake) supports multiple rows in the `VALUES` clause and as such, I'd like to leverage `:values` as the strategy instead. I have not found this to be an option that I can pass in.

Default strategy:
https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/9202d780b92626646c9faeff90a7f7b9d7b6c10d/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb#L1340

`multi_insert` code:
https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/ff5d77cb60a61b41d3eb500344f287f0b9fbdb97/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb#L484

Options available for `import` which is used by `multi_insert`:
https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jeremyevans/sequel/Sequel%2FDataset:import

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can override the strategy:

```
DB.extend_datasets do
  def multi_insert_sql_strategy; :values; end
end
```

In general, you may want to consider working on an Sequel adapter for Snowflake, as this is something the adapter is supposed to take care of.